# Flattening Dataset[Dataset[Column]] to Dataset[Column]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to capture metadata of all the tables of a database. I am using `spark.catalog` api to extract the metadata. I wrote following method

```
def getColumns(tables:Dataset[Table]): Dataset[Column] = {
  tables.map(table => spark.catalog.listColumns(table.name))
}
```

This method returns `Dataset[Dataset[Colums]]`. How can I convert it into `Dataset[Column]` so it can be saved as table in hive? Please recommend if there is any other efficient way to capture all the table's metadata.

Answer (score 1):

```
    // 1. only column name

    val c1 = spark.catalog.listColumns("database-name.table-name").select('name)
    // c1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string]
    c1.printSchema
    // root
    //  |-- name: string (nullable = true)

    // 2. Full info
       

    val c1 = spark.catalog.listColumns("database-name.table-name")
    // c1: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.catalog.Column] = [name: 
    string, description: string ... 4 more fields]

    c1.printSchema
    // root
    //  |-- name: string (nullable = true)
    //  |-- description: string (nullable = true)
    //  |-- dataType: string (nullable = true)
    //  |-- nullable: boolean (nullable = false)
    //  |-- isPartition: boolean (nullable = false)
    //  |-- isBucket: boolean (nullable = false)

// 3. All info about columns in tables database
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val dbName = "set database name"

val listTables = spark.catalog.listTables(dbName)
  .select('name).as[String]
  .collect().toList

val listDF = listTables.map(t => {
  val colsDF = spark.catalog.listColumns(dbName, t)
    .withColumn("namneTable", lit(t))
    .withColumn("dbName", lit(dbName))

  colsDF
})

val resDF = listDF.reduce(_ union _)

resDF.printSchema
//  root
//  |-- name: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- description: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- dataType: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- nullable: boolean (nullable = false)
//  |-- isPartition: boolean (nullable = false)
//  |-- isBucket: boolean (nullable = false)
//  |-- namneTable: string (nullable = false)
//  |-- dbName: string (nullable = false)

resDF.write.format("parquet").saveAsTable(.....)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have requirement of capturing all the columns (as you shown in #2. Full info) OF ALL THE DATABASE TABLES  and then stored it in one hive table. I can do it in foreach loop but it takes way too long and eventually runs out of driver memory. I have more than 4000 tables in a database. So I am thinking of running a map on list of tables and pass table name to spark.catalog.listColumns and save result into dataframe which I can write it to hive. But map output will be Dataset[Dataset[Column]]. So I want to flatten/convert it into Dataset[Column]

Comment: Please, see to Hive Metastore. Tables: DBS, TBLS, SDS, PARTITIONS, ... all tables = 55.

Comment: edit my answer. add item 3. All info about columns in tables database. In your method try use flatMap.